# gridrow delete event causing infinite loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to add a delete column to my gridview, however when I press the delete button on a row, it calls the function I assigned to onRowDeleting infinitely or so it seems.

Here's my code:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="yep" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDeleting="dismissClick">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Create Incident">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Selections" runat="server" ViewStateMode = "Enabled" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="case#" HeaderText="Case #" SortExpression="case#" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Unit #" HeaderText="Unit #" SortExpression="Unit #" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="date" SortExpression="date" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="typeOfCall" HeaderText="typeOfCall" SortExpression="typeOfCall" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Primary Impression" HeaderText="Primary Impression" SortExpression="Primary Impression" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View PCR">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="ViewPCR" Text="View PCR" runat="server" OnClick="viewPCRClick" CssClass="btn em" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dismiss">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="dismiss" Text="Dismiss" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CssClass="btn em" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
```

and my simple deletion function:

```
   protected void dismissClick(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e) 
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
        GridView1.DeleteRow(index);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `GridView1.DeleteRow(index)` is causing an event loop, because calling that method also raises the `RowDeleted` and `RowDeleting` events again, as described in the MSDN documentation for [GridView.DeleteRow Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.deleterow.aspx):

```
Calling this method also raises the RowDeleted and RowDeleting events.
```

Instead you want to either remove it from the binding source (i.e. `DataSet`, `DataTable`, `List<T>` or whatever you are binding to) or persist your delete to the database or whatever is ultimately holding your data and then re-bind the grid.

Comment: Ah, so the gridview is binded to a database table on the company server. So I need to do some query coding to delete it form the data source? What might that look like?

Comment: @WillTuttle - how are you binding the grid with in-line SQL (i.e. `"SELECT * FROM xyz..."` or a stored procedure)?

Comment: I'm using a function written into a webservice project I'll post it.